# How to fix a ParametricNDSolveValue? - Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, warning-messages

[image]

How to fix a `ParametricNDSolveValue`? - "ParametricNDSolveValue::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0."

I have tried everything. But I keeps coming up with errors.

```
soP = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y''[t]+ by'[t]+k1y@t + k2hf[y@t]=10+ a Sin[w t],y[0]=-.1,y'[0]=.2},{y@t,y'[t]},{t,tz},{k1,k2,a,w,b,tz}]

sb1 = soP[13, 5, .1, 4, .01];

{Plot[sb1,{t,0,100}],ParametricPlot[sb1,{t,0,100},Frame->True,AspectRatio->2]}
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: You need to post your code, not images of your code.

Comment: `hf[]` is undefined, it appears.  Or maybe you need a space between the 2 and the h in `k2hf`.

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: YOu define soP as an expression "soP=.. " but you use it as a function: "soP[13, 5, .1, 4, .01]". You must define SoP as function like: soP[arguments,..]:= ..